# Vectorization of Matrix in Tensor Notation

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

How can I express the vecorization of a matrix A (vec(A)) in tensor notation? I have problems finding the correct use of indices such that the contraction runs correctly.

Comment: I don't know. Isn't it easier to assume some vectorization and to express the tensor operations in terms of matrices working on such vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have an element of $F^{m \times n}$ and you vectorize to an element of $F^{(m \cdot n)}$ where $F$ is some field (likely $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).

With $i \in [1,m\cdot n]$ an index for your vector and $j \in [1,m], k \in [1,n]$ indices for your matrix, contract along $j$ and $k$ with 
$$ \epsilon_{ik}^j = \delta_{i,(j-1)n+k} = \begin{cases}
1  &,  i = (j-1)n+k \\
0  &,  \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}  \text{.}  $$
For instance $\mathrm{vec}(M) = M^j_i \epsilon^{ik}_j$

(Haven't tested this.  Off-by-one errors are likely.)